# Write a function, write a pattern

Tags: functions, pattern-matching

I have the following list:

```
list = {{1, 2, 4}, 6, 7, 8, {8, 2}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}, {1, 2, 3, 1}};
```

(a) I should write a predicate-function in combination with an select

(b) I should write a pattern in combination with cases

to get all subexpressions where the sum is 7.

That should be the result: `{{1,2,4},7,{3,4},{1,2,3,1}}`

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Does `Select[list, Total[{#}, Infinity] == 7&]` work?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: This appears to be homework.  This site does not exist to solve homework problems for you.  You should include what you have tried and where you ran into trouble.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because routine do-my-homework question

Answer (score 1):

```
Select[list, Plus @@ # == 7 &];
Cases[list, _?(Plus @@ # == 7 &)];
```

Comment: What does `Plus @@ 7` do?

Comment: Default[Plus] is 0 which means Plus @@ 7 is 7+0=7

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. [Apply documentation, possible issues](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html#subOuter6): "Applying to atomic objects that do not have subparts effectively does nothing". `f @@ 7 (* 7 *)`

Comment: @Algohi `Default[Plus]` is not used here. `Unprotect[Plus]; Default[Plus] = 100; Plus @@ 7 (* 7 *)`

Comment: @jkuczm, good catch. Thanks

Comment: @jkuczm, ah yes. Thanks! Looked weird at first blush, tho.

Answer (score 0):

```
list = {{1, 2, 4}, 6, 7, 8, {8, 2}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}, {1, 2, 3, 1}};
```

`Select[list, crit]` is equivalent to `Cases[list, _?(crit)]`

```
Select[list, Total[{#} // Flatten] == 7 &]
```

> {{1, 2, 4}, 7, {3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 1}}

```
Cases[list, _?(Total[{#} // Flatten] == 7 &)]
```

> {{1, 2, 4}, 7, {3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 1}}

```
% == %%
```

> True

Comment: Judicious use of `Total[]`'s second argument obviates the need for `Flatten[]`. The `(* pattern *) /; (* condition *)` construct is also usable in `Cases[]`.